# Need C# to save date into sql server as sql server datetime e.g. 2016-05-19 12:46:08.610

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, datetime-format

I need to have C# via Entity Framework save current datetime to sql server into table column of datatype `datetime`

Was reading that `DateTime.Now` in C# is not going to be correct ... 
so I stumbled across where a guy posted that he was doing this as it saves down to the proper millisecond

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime entry2 
    = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(new DateTime(dto.LookUpDateTime));
DateTime entry = entry2.Value;
```

Now I assumed with the `Overloads` that I should be able to just do this:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime dt 
    = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(new DateTime());
```

**However, I get an error in catch block saying**  'sqldatatime overflow...`

```
DateTime dateTime = dt.Value;

rpmuser.lst_pwd_chg_dtm = dateTime;
rpmuser.cre_dtm = dateTime;
```

Can I use DateTime.Now or what do I need to do to get this **SqlDateTime** to work?

Comment: Whatever you read was wrong. Use parameters, and use `DateTime.Now`, and let the DB driver do any necessary conversions.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because you are trying to store a date that is outside the supported range.  On MS SQL Server the `datetime` field type can hold datetime values in the range `1-Jan-1753 00:00:00` to `31-Dec-9999 23:59:59.997` inclusive.  This is narrower than the range explicitly supported by the .NET `DateTime` type (`1-Jan-0001 00:00:00` to `31-Dec-9999 23:59:59` plus a fraction).  So any date prior to `1-Jan-1753` will cause that error.

A common problem is when you use either `DateTime.MinValue` to indicate a specific state of your data but don't filter that to something the SQL field can contain before sending the data to the database.  The solution in this case would be to define a suitable lower boundary of the data and define a static value that is lower but still within the SQL range.

If your data needs to include dates and times outside of the valid range for the SQL `datetime` field type then you might want to use the `datetime2` field type which has the same effective range as the .NET `DateTime` type.  Which is unsurprising since it appears to be the same data structure - count of 100ns ticks since `1-1-1`.